# Commandbutton with dynamic numbers

Tags: excel, vba

How would I go about creating dynamic Commandbutton references? i.e. change

```
MANAGER.CommandButton01.Caption = Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & Rows)
```

(which works perfectly, but only on one button of course) - to, for example:

```
MANAGER.CommandButton("0" & (Rows - 2)).Caption = Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & Rows)
```

(this code doesn't work, but it's what I've been playing around with)

So that the Commandbutton's caption is updated depending on which line of code was edited using the MANAGER Userform.

Rows can be double digits, so the "0" will have to be replaced with just Rows after Row 11, but I haven't gotten to that stage yet.

Comment: Could you share the `If...Then` or `Select Case` statement where this would be used? I wanna play, too.

Comment: Can you show the method where this code is executed?

Comment: The code is spread over several modules and a Userform, but all it is, is values on the DATA sheet with a 2-row offset (due to headers) so button01 is linked to row 3 data, button02 to row 4 data, etc. The MANAGER Userform simply pulls in the data for the respective row - from where the user can then edit the values. Clicking the update button, then writes these values back to the corresponding row. The trick is that the user can change the data "name" which is also displayed as the button caption - so if the row "name" changes, then I need to update the commandbutton caption too.

Comment: For example, if you are writing to row 4's data, then commandbutton02's caption needs to update / refresh. I haven't managed to get the code above to work, but a crude workaround that does work, is to call the initialize module code again. This just goes through all the rows and updates all the Commandbutton captions on the Userform with the latest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the reference to the Controls of the userform.

```
MANAGER.Controls("CommandButton" & Format(Rows-2,"00")).Caption = Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & Rows)
```